# Split dataframe to different days

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple data frame in Pandas

```
0   2020-12-03 12:00:00  122.219985  122.798140  121.821258  122.703443   9204466
1   2020-12-03 13:00:00  122.708427  122.838013  122.349572  122.494111   6596303
2   2020-12-03 14:00:00  122.489226  122.638649  122.205033  122.269826   5510204
3   2020-12-04 10:00:00  122.359540  122.469988  121.153389  121.681703  12470960
4   2020-12-04 11:00:00  121.671735  121.791353  121.133453  121.402594  11617192
5   2020-12-04 12:00:00  121.400799  122.274810  121.233134  121.983540   8799353
.......
```

The date column called `Datetime`, and i am trying to split this data frame into **array of dataframes** where each element is a `dataframe` of a single day, with indexes starting from 0.

```
array = [df0,df1,..]
```

df0 :

```
0   2020-12-03 12:00:00  122.219985  122.798140  121.821258  122.703443   9204466
1   2020-12-03 13:00:00  122.708427  122.838013  122.349572  122.494111   6596303
...
```

df1:

```
0   2020-12-04 10:00:00  122.359540  122.469988  121.153389  121.681703  12470960
1   2020-12-04 11:00:00  121.671735  121.791353  121.133453  121.402594  11617192
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
d = {x: y for x , y in df.groupby(df['yourdate'].dt.date)}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot BENY.

Comment: I am not sure how to get an array of this, and how to also restart the indexes per line in the same line ?

Comment: @Shulas d = {x: y.reset_index(drop=True) for x , y in df.groupby(df['yourdate'].dt.date)}